# Turn on automatic language detection on Office 2016 for OS X?

Tags: macos, language, microsoft-office-2016

According to [this article](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Turn-on-automatic-language-detection-194d309c-3e10-4bd5-a694-ba9bbdf4a28e) Office 2016 should be able to detect languages automatically. However, the option / checkbox to activate is simply not there in OS X (Outlook version 15.25 (160817)).

I remember it actually working in an earlier release of Office 2016. Also OS X has built-in language detection. So I wonder if there is a way to activate it in some way. Any hints?